# Electron with shadcn/vue config (src) confusion

Tags: vue.js, electron, tailwind-css, shadcnui, electron-vue

As you can see I have two src/components (assets), one is in the root, the other in the /renderer. The root one was created when I added resizable components via "npx shadcn-vue@latest add resizable" (I think). Doesn't feel right. Somebody please explain how the paths should be in such configuration (Electron app using shadcn/vue) so that I can add shadcn components and properly import them. Or if you have some useful guiding links.
[image: The file folder explorer along with various .config files.]

Answer (score 0):

**Add alias for `ui` in your `components.json` as bellow**

```json
{
  "aliases": {
    "ui": "src/renderer/src/components",
    "utils": "src/utils"
  }
}
```

Your can learn more [here](https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components-json)